# Do VPC service availability zones need to match VPC endpoint zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm setting up a VPC endpoint for a corresponding VPC service endpoint.

- Our app calls the downstream service using a non- region or
  zone-specific name (routed to the VPCe).
- We have 3 app subnets set on the VPCe (corresponding to 3
  availability zones us-west-2a, -2b, -2c).
- The service we're calling supports only 2 availability zones
  (us-west-2a, -2b).
- When creating the endpoint (via CloudFormation) I get the following
  error:

  `The VPC endpoint service com.amazonaws.vpce.us-west-2.vpce-svc-01234567890123456 does not support the availability zone of the subnet: subnet-0abcdef0123456789. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: ...)`

(Where that subnet is in AZ us-west-2c)

What's the fix here?

I can't leave out that subnet without preventing our app in that AZ from using the VPCe, right?

Seems like AWS expects the client and service AZs to match?
I must be misunderstanding something though. Would not expect it to be this rigid. (For example, if `service us-west-2c` goes down, requests from `client us-west-2c` should go to `service us-west-2a` or `-2b`. That's the whole point of AZs, right?)

Comment: >> Seems like AWS expects the client and service AZs to match? I must be misunderstanding something though. Would not expect it to be this rigid.....


> Compute in us-east-1a calling ddb in us-east-1a through gateway endpoints.  if DDB in us-east-1a goes down, does this make the compute useless since the data store may not be responding?

Comment: > Or is this only applicable only for services with Interface endpoints (not Gateway endpoints) ?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible.  Here is an example using Terraform:

```
locals {
  subnet_count     = length(data.aws_availability_zones.non_local.names)
  cidr_block      = "10.0.0.0/16"
  region           = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "demo" {
  cidr_block = local.cidr_block
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  ...
}

resource "aws_subnet" "demo" {
  count             = local.subnet_count
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.demo.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(local.cidr_block, ceil(log(local.subnet_count, 2)), count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.non_local.names[count.index]
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "non_local" {
  # No Local Zones
  # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones#by-filter
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ses" {
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.demo.id
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.${local.region}.email-smtp"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  subnet_ids = data.aws_subnet_ids.ses.ids
}

data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "ses" {
  service = "email-smtp"
}

data "aws_subnets" "ses" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [aws_vpc.demo.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "subnet-id"
    values = aws_subnet.demo.*.id
  }

  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone"
    values = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.ses.availability_zones
  }
}
```

Comment: This works well. I had no idea the _real_ zone names were different between accounts!

Answer (score 1):

Did some more research, and found:

- The correct subnet(s) can't be determined automatically.
- The producer / consumer zones do need to match.
- The AWS console's create VPC Endpoint screen can be used to check available service AZs.
- There should be no issue communicating from `client us-west-2c` to a `client VPCe in us-west-2a` as long *as the security group of the VPCe allows for it*.

The solution will have to involve manually checking for supported availability zones in the service.

Comment: The correct subnet(s) appear to be automatically discoverable using aws-cdk: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/7521